# When a decimal column is mapped to a typehinted float property, doctrine updates a field even if not changed

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a User class, with the field

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=12, scale=6)
 */
private float $credit = 0;
```

Or with php8, same behavior:

```
private int|float $credit = 0;
```

If I load a user, even without changing anything, at the next flush(), doctrine will send a query to update its credit:

[image]

(This is very dangerous because the credit may have been changed in the meanwhile by another script, reverting the change. The credit isn't supposed to be edited directly from the application, there isn't even a setCredit() method... )

By adding some dumping in the preUpdate() method, I found the value is changed from:

`"-10746.000000"` (string)

To:

`-10746.000000` (float)

This is not happening if I remove the typehint on the private property:

```
private $credit = 0; // Working, credit is not updated to db
```

Why is this happening? Am I doing something wrong or I should report it as a bug?

Comment: @yivi yes sorry, I edited the question. It happens for 2 fields only, they are 'type="decimal", precision=12, scale=6'. The value is read from db

Comment: If they are a string isn't there the risk that operations like `+` cause a concatenation instead of an addition?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For `decimal` fields, Doctrine will retrieve the data as a `string` or `null`. This is explained on the docs, [here](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html#decimal-types).

Since you are defining the property as a `float`, you force Doctrine to do some type juggling when retrieving the data, which in turn causes the confusing about the entity being 'dirty': the value retrieved from the DB is **not** equal to the value that is stored on the property, e.g. `'123.12' !== 123.12`.

You should use the type `string` for `decimal` properties.

Then you either you cast to `float` when you want to perform a mathematical operation, or you use something like [BC Math](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) if you are interested in precision (which is usually the case when using a `decimal` type).